# Will publishing a package with a git submodule using apm include the submodule?

Tags: git, github, atom-editor, git-submodules

I have a git repository and I want to leave a separate git repo with fonts as a submodule. Can I leave it as a submodule for apm to pick it up correctly with the included submodule or do I need to add the files separately from git repository?

Will apm publish the package with with the repository on github added in to the main repository?

Comment: For anyone else confused by this, "apm" is apparently the Atom Package Manager which is something included with the Atom editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. See [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6700) for reference and keep in mind that `apm` is a fork of `npm`.

In my opinion, the Node-way is to install a repository as a standard dependency (see [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls)). However, this requires the extra step of copying the files to the desired target location. This can be done in the [`postinstall` script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).